# Efeito skew com css

Tags: html, css

Pessoal precisava fazer um efeito `skew` via `css`  `transform: skew(40deg);` porem ao fazer isso ele distorce o texto do meu link também gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de fazer isso para somente alterar o `background-color` do meu link lembrando que vai ter um `:hover` também segue o código;

Css:

```
background-color: rgba(22, 47, 76, 0.4117647058823529);
padding: 25px 20px 27px;
display: block;
color: @white;
font-weight: bold;
transform: skew(40deg);
```

Html:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline list-menu-client hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Meira Online</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Holerites</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Banco de Negócios</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

É isso que acontece com meu menu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
até o text do menu aplica esse efeito e fica distorcido como resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa aplicar o `skew` no `li` e no `a` (texto) fazer o **inverso**. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
li {
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
li a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: red;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Outros</a></li>
</ul>
```